# Count rows in database and echo out desired row number

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

If I have 5 rows in my mysql database with ids of 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8 and I echo out id 5 how do I then echo out the row number which of course would be row 3? I get row 3 by counting all the rows from the start of the database to the row I am after.

Comment: It appears you already realise the solution might involve `count`.  So what have you tried already?

Comment: Remember that you can't count on this row number to be constant. SQL query without `ORDER BY` clause doesn't guarantee any order.

Comment: I've tried a block of code which echos all the rows I have in the database, and another piece of code which can echo out how many rows in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_number, id from table inner join (select @row_num:=0) as temp

$pdo = new PDO(....);
$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: +1 You can also use a UNION instead of a JOIN to initialize the variable - handy if you want to avoid the overhead of a join: `SELECT NULL AS row_num, NULL AS id FROM dual WHERE (@row_num := 0) 
UNION ...` The WHERE produces an *Impossible WHERE*, so it doesn't return any rows, but it does initialize the variable.

Comment: Ok, I've been using php for about a year so I know quite a bit but never have I come across a query like this. How exactly are you suppose to echo it out?

Comment: @Martin L: `@row_num` is a [user-defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html).  It's handy for producing dynamic values in a query.  If you do `SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS row_num`, then `row_num` will be returned as one of the columns in your query - just like a real column.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be to add some auto_increment key to your table, then each row would have assigned a sequential number. Otherwise you are not guaranteed to get the same number for each id because SQL query without `ORDER BY` clause is not guaranteed to have any order (i.e. ids may be returned in random order).

Otherwise, the solution given by Andrej L is the correct one.

Comment: I made the ID column to be auto_increment when I first created the database.

Comment: A better description on what you are trying to achieve would help. Currently I see no real reason to do the counting you need.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just count the number of rows before this in the sort order you're using?

```
COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id < ?
```

In this case only rows with id 2 and 3 would count, so the result is 2. If you're using a 1-based index, add one to that and you have your answer.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know what's happening with it.